# A dangling participle in The Economist?

Tags: grammar, dangling-participles

This paragraph is [published](https://www.economist.com/science-and-technology/2020/06/06/have-siberian-fires-been-smouldering-underground-all-winter) in *The Economist,* Jun 6th 2020 edition as "Have Siberian fires been smouldering underground all winter?"

The part of ***Nestled...*** in the highlighted sentence looks like a dangling participle to me. The subject of the main clause is *satellites* which does not seem to agree with *nestled*.

No offence to the professionals. I am just wondering if journalists would also have a lapse in grammar.

> SEEN FROM the sky, the northern stretches of Siberia in early May were
> a splodgy white, their thinning winter snow cover interrupted by the
> brown veins of meandering rivers. **Nestled within some of these curves,
> though, satellites picked up patches of soil warmer than the ground
> around them.** The patches grew and multiplied as the month went on.
> Before it was over, some were visibly ablaze.

Here are my versions. Comments are welcomed.

1. Passive voice

Nestled within some of these curves, though, patches of soil warmer than the ground around them were picked up by satellite.

2. Preposition structure

Between some of these curves, though, satellites picked up patches of soil warmer than the ground around them.

What do you think?

Comment: Presumably writers and editors are only human.

Comment: So how would you write it?

Comment: Why does it seem completely alright to me?

Comment: Yes, I think it's a dangler since the "nestled" clause doesn't refer to the nearest NP, the subject "satellites", but to the object of "up", "patches of soil ...". One alternant might be: "Satellites picked up patches of soil warmer than the ground around them, nestled within some of the curves".

Comment: You should **not** make major additions to a question after it has received an answer, and in this case several comments, too.

Comment: How does substituting "Between" for "Nestled within" change anything??

Comment: Sorry BillJ. I meant to add this in the comments before I saw the prompt in the comment box "If you are adding information, edit your post instead of commenting." I'm new here and probably I took it wrong. My fault.

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong.

My understanding the sentence with "Between.." is grammarly correct but I have to admit the meaning still ambiguous.

From what I learned, the participle in the sub clause has to agree with the subject of the main sentence, otherwise it is grammarly incorrect.

In the case of preposition structure, it does not have a subject-verb agreement issue because there is no verb in the structure.

More examples:
Walking along the trail, I saw many trees. (correct)
Laid on the table, I saw a gun.  (incorrect)
On the table I saw a gun.  (seems okay)

Answer (score 4):

Satellites picked up something that nestled somewhere.

There's nothing inherently *wrong* with the syntax of the example - it's just potentially ambiguous to pedants who might suppose it's the *satellites* that were nestling, rather than whatever they picked up.

But that's a pointlessly perverse interpretation. Whether I say *Hiding in the bushes I saw a fox* or *I saw a fox hiding in the bushes*, you should probably assume it was the ***fox*** that was in the bushes, not me. And that doesn't change if I use ***hidden*** rather than ***hiding***, nor if I discard that verb completely and just stick with the preposition ***in** the bushes* - or, say, ***among** the bushes*.

Comment: And we do have a specifc way of forcing the latter - *while* hiding in the bushes ...